# django binary (no source code) deployment

Tags: python, django, binary

is there possible only to deploy binary version of web application based on django , no source code publish?

Thanks

Comment: protect the code i guess, you have a web application and you need to deploy to your client's (many clients) sever

Comment: I am dubious about whis. Protect from what?
I can't see the danger that a web application poses. Access to the source code is more a server configuration/permissions problem… or am I missing the point entirely?

Comment: i need to deploy the whole application to client's machine/server, i am not hosting the web application, my client will host the application locally

Answer (score 12):

Oh, again that old one... Simply stated, you can't deploy an application in a non-compiled language (Python, Perl, PHP, Ruby...) in a source-safe way - all existing tricks are extremely easy to circumvent. Anyway, that doesn't matter at all: the contract you have with your customer does. Even for Java  there are neat decompilers.

If your customer wants to redeploy by hand your application on another machine, he could anyway even if the application was in C. Unless you wrote a dongle-protected anti-piracy scheme? Come on. You have to build a relation with your client. This is a social, commercial and legal problem that **can't** be solved with a technical stunt.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, sort of.

Have a read of http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm - that should answer your question!

Comment: Please note that if you're interested on "hidding" the source there are tools that can generate the Python code from the pyc files (including comments!.)

Comment: The website seems to down, here an archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20200203142427/http://effbot.org/zone/python-compile.htm

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a reliable to do this at the moment. Even compiled code like referenced in the answer above this one isn't 100% secure.

**My advice:** clean open code for your clients and a good relation with them is the only way to go. Keeping your code hidden can be good from a business point of view but from a client relation point of view it's a real show stopper. Advertise: "Our code is open!", which doesn't mean your clients can do anything they want with it.

Comment: I think this comes again and again from programmers who'd like to solve problems with programming even when they're unrelated. Once again an illustration of the famous engineering proverb :"when all you have is a hammer, all problems look like nails" :)